Is this question fitting here?
Have a look to this question:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/117495/consequence-of-order-in-a-survey
I wonder if it's more correlated to the science of cognition or to the pure statistics.
Can you give me a suggestion?

I don't see how that is a statistics question. You are asking how a pre-rated list of items influences someone that has to rate them? And possibly how to prevent this bias? The latter seems an easy answer, don't show the votes and randomize presentation across participants.

yes.. it's exactly what I'm asking. I've improved the question now and made it very more clear by completely rewriting it. Consider that most of the lists are sorted. Imdb, classifics and so on.. Statistic may wonder on the correlation between the position and the bias of visibility.
